# SQL Triggers - Compare New values, if rule is broken, revert back to old values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was just curious if it was possible to configure a trigger that would watch for table updates and then:

1. Look at the row with the new data.
2. Grab the new data.
3. Run the data through a series of rules.

   - If the data doesn't follow a rule then revert the entire row back before the update.
   - Else do nothing.

Comment: Look up how transactions work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger as you normally would. Here is a good breakdown of the structure of a trigger: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm

You can use the `:NEW` attribute to access the new data being entered, store it in a variable (if you choose), then execute your validation on the data. If it doesn't pass any of them then raise and error; that will exit the trigger and not update the field with the new data.

For more information on exceptions in triggers see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS751

Hope this helps.